# Rails thinks "faves" is referring to a model named "Fafe"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions, camelcasing

I have a model named `Fave`. It belongs to another model named `User`.

I'm trying to find a User's Faves by calling `@user.faves`. My server gives me back the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant User::Fafe
```

Why would it think the singular of "faves" is "fafe"? Is there some other plural form I can use that will point to "fave"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the class name while setting up the association

```
has_many :faves, class_name: "Fave"
```

Answer (score 2):

Can we try this in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`? This could work

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'fave', 'faves' #append this to the existing ones
end
```

Comment: This seems likely. I know that the regexp that Rails depends on to find the plural inflection of "sleeve" will return "sleefe" rather than "sleeves." Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32337665/table-pluralization/32337815#32337815) for more details on how inflections work in Rails.